# javascripts files not linking to my category slugs?

Tags: categories, javascript, links

I have a wordpress custom theme set-up and what i want is to create separate category templates, now seeing the template hierarchy i created the category-{slug} file and now when i am linking my custom JavaScript files inside its header part the script inserted in header is -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../literature/js/head.min.js"></script>
```

And the scripts in the footer to be executed after my content loads are -

```
<script>
        head.js(
            { jquery : "js/jquery.min.js" },
            { mousewheel : "js/jquery.mousewheel.js" },
            { mwheelIntent : "js/mwheelIntent.js" },
            { jScrollPane : "js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js" },
            { history : "js/jquery.history.js" },
            { stringLib : "js/core.string.js" },
            { easing : "js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" },
            { smartresize : "js/jquery.smartresize.js" },
            { page : "js/jquery.page.js" }
        );
</script>
```

Now i am getting a 404 error for all these files not present there , here's the firebug result :-

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/deadman/wordpress/category/literature/wp-content/themes/testing/js/literature/core.string.js"
```

Now the things which i already tried are

- `"<?php bloginfo('template_url');/js/literature?>"`
- `"wp-content/themes/testing/js/literature"`

Anyone got a possible solution for this, i think it is because of the javascript prototyping i am using in the footer part but still i ain't able to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Relative URLs are best avoided in WP, so use absolute URLs instead. Also, you should load javascript files using the correct method, ie by using the [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function hooked to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook. Doing both of these things will sort out your issue. Using `wp_enqueue_script()` will also allow you to define dependencies so, for example, you don't load jQuery twice (in the event the theme or another plugin is already loading it). The page I linked to shows an example of the code you need.

Comment: I think i tried both the relative and the absolute urls, but am not able to work it out, anyway let me try the wp_enqueue_script() method